# symfony2のプロファイラの設定

Tags: php, symfony2

お世話になります。symfony2の勉強中です。
新たにバンドルを作成して新規でページを作成しておりますが、インストールしたてのdemoページにあるようなプロファイラが表示されません。
demoのAcmeバンドルを削除すると以下のようなエラーが出てプロファイラの表示で500エラーが出ているようでした。
    Attempted to call method "loadTemplate" on class "__TwigTemplate_ef63bb20994ec747f2bebabd9b9b53d082e36907cc912d51e24b218c506321a8".
demo画面では問題なくプロファイラが動いているのですが、自作のバンドル内でも機能するように設定するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

CentOS6(final)
PHP 5.4.40 (cli)
Symfony version 2.6.6

Comment: Acmeバンドルを削除したというのは、具体的に何を削除されたのでしょうか。（どこかのディレクトリを消したorファイル内の記述を消した）

Comment: ありがとうございます。
Acmeバンドルの削除の方法が正確にはわからなかったので、新しい環境にAcmeバンドルなしでインストールしたというのが正確な言い方になります。紛らわしくてすみません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**プロファイラーの件**

プロファイラーを表示しようとしている画面は`<HTML>`タグや`<BODY>`タグで囲まれていますでしょうか？
Symfonyのプロファイラーは`</body>`タグの直前にjsで後からレンダリングするような仕組みとなっています。
プロファイラーが動いている(プロファイラーが有効な)状態なのであれば、HTMLでマークアップされたページを表示すればおそらく出てくるだろうと思います。

以下のように最低限のマークアップを行いプロファイラーが表示されるか試してみてください。

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

**AcmeDemoBundle削除の件**

> Attempted to call method "loadTemplate" on class
>   "__TwigTemplate_ef63bb20994ec747f2bebabd9b9b53d082e36907cc912d51e24b218c506321a8".

こちらのエラーがなぜ発生しているのか一概には言えないのですが、エラー自体は存在していないcacheファイルを読もうとしているのが原因です。試しに 「php app/console cache:clear」 もしくは 「rm -rf app/cache/dev/*」 を実行してみてください。

AcmeBundleの削除が上手くいっていればこれで動くようになると思います。

また AcmeDemoBundleの削除方法についてはこちらにドキュメントがありますのでご参考にどうぞ。

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html

Comment: Okada様
ありがとうございます。twigのテンプレートにhtmlを加えたらプロファイラーが現れました。
エラーについてはまだ原因がわからずです。追って調査中です。